# Проверить, что все элементы списка соответствуют условию

Tags: python

Допустим есть список N - длинны элементов, как проверить, что все его элементы больше нуля. И если это так, то вывести из функции булевое значение равное True. Пробовал через разные циклы реализовать (В частотности через for … in …:), так и ничего не вышло.

Пробовал что-то типа такого кода:

```
for pangram in pangrams:
    if pangram != 0:
        pass
```

Comment: `return all(x > 0 for x in sequence)`.

Comment: Слова "пробовал через..." всегда должны сопровождаться кодом.

Comment: Прикрепил одну из своих попыток, так и не додумался, что вставить вместо pass.

Comment: Я пока только в начале своего пути на питоне(ну и программировании в целом). И люди, которые пишут сортировки в одну строку для меня выглядят, как чернокнижники владеющие тайными знаниями. Поэтому пытаюсь все делать через циклы да условные конструкции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

воспользоваться стандартной функцией `all`:

```
arr = [1, 2, -3]

res = all(map(lambda x: x > 0, arr))
```

чуть более короткий вариант с использованием того же подхода:

```
res = all([x > 0 for x in arr])
```

совет от CrazyElf делает код еще короче:

```
res = all(x > 0 for x in arr)
```

**P.S.**

немного изврата с использованием стандартных функций:

```
res = len(list(filter(lambda x: x <= 0, arr))) == 0
```

или тоже самое, но чуть короче:

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: x <= 0, arr)) == []
```

Comment: [занудствует] Квадратные скобки во втором примере лишние! ))

Comment: век живи век учись - точно, я как то и не задумывался

Comment: Михаил Муругов раньше меня тут такой вариант в комментарии к вопросу дал если что )  Но вообще да, надо знать, что в круглых скобках можно скобки от generator comprehesnion опускать, но сначала нужно сообразить, что надо на него list comprehension поменять )

Comment: @CrazyElf `> надо знать, что в круглых скобках можно скобки от generator comprehesnion опускать` не всегда =) если в генераторе используются запятые / функция принимает более одного аргумента, то опускать их уже нельзя. Нужно ставить либо круглые скобки для чёткого определения генератора, либо квадратные для чёткого определения списка по генератору

Comment: @CrazyElf, а вот не уверен, поскольку `arr = [1, 2, 3, 0]` выдаст `True`, а должен `False`

Comment: Хм, да, странно... что-то я не додумал. Уберу каммент )

Comment: @Евгений Ну, всегда можно найти контрпримеры усложнённые )

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(list_):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, list_))) == len(list_)
```

с помощью `filter` оставляем только те элементы которые больше нулю, превращаем в список, сравниваем длину получившегося списка и начального

либо так:

```
def f(list_):
    return min(list_) >= 0
```

Comment: Конструкция `if ...: return True` в данном случае не только нагромождает решение, но и меняет тип результата. Ваша функция возвращает не (`True` либо `False`), а (`True` либо `None`)

Comment: @Евгений готово :)

Comment: Сейчас ваше второе решение возвращает ровно обратный результат. Если есть отрицательные числа, то будет `True`, а если их нет - `False`

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю функционального изврату )

```
from operator import lt
from functools import partial

print(all(map(partial(lt, 0), [1, 2, 3, -1])))
print(all(map(partial(lt, 0), [1, 2, 3, 4])))
print(all(map(partial(lt, 0), [1, 2, 0, 4])))
```

Вывод:

```
False
True
False
```

Хотя тут получается как бы наоборот - проверяется, что 0 меньше каждого из элементов списка.

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернатива:

```
not any(x<=0 for x in [1, 2, 5, 4, 0]) # False
not any(x<=0 for x in [1, 2, 5, 4, 7]) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция, эквивалентная конструкции `all(x > 0 for x in arr)`:

```
def all_positive(pangrams):
    for pangram in pangrams:
        if pangram <= 0:
            # Если встретился элемент не больше нуля, сразу выходим из функции и возвращаем False
            return False  
    
    # Если дошли до сюда, значит все элементы больше нуля (или список пустой),
    #  возвращаем True 
    return True
```